# java.lang.unsupportedoperationexception The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I'm new to hibernate and I'm trying to write a simple program I faced with error for this line in java code:

```
session.beginTransaction();
```

this is my `hibernate.cfg.xml` code:

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- JDBC Database conncetion settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="conncetion.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false</property>
    <property name="conncetion.username">hbstudent</property>
    <property name="connection.password">hbstudent</property>

    <!-- JDBC conncetion pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
    <property name="conncetion.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- set the current session context -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

</session-factory>
```

and the java file:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;

public class CreateStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                    .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                                    .buildSessionFactory();

        //create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try{
            // use the session object to save java object

            //create a student object
            System.out.println("Creating new student object");
            Student tempStudent = new Student("Paul", "Wall", "paul@luv2code.com");

            //start a transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            //save the student object
            System.out.println("Saving the student...");
            session.save(tempStudent);

            //commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Done!");

        }
        finally{
           factory.close();
        }

    }
}
```

I'm using hibernate 5.2.1 just in case.
I also checked other questions but none of them could help.

Comment: what about your problem ? or any error message ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have typo error. Change `conncetion` to `connection`, i.e.

```
<property name="conncetion.url">
<property name="conncetion.username">
<property name="conncetion.pool_size">
```

to

```
<property name="connection.url">
<property name="connection.username">
<property name="connection.pool_size">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use hibernate in your name attribute like:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">
```

and there is also spell mistake use **connection** instead of **conncetion**